# Encontrar el número mayor en una lista AngularJS(Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic

Quiero encontrar el número mayor en una aplicación híbrida, usando ionic, entonces tengo mi controlador:

```
.controller('miControlador', function($scope) {
    $scope.datos=[];
    $scope.numeros=[];

    $scope.Agregar=function(item) {
        $scope.numeros.push(item);
    };
});
```

ahi crea la lista con los datos ingresados desde la interfaz, lo que quiero saber, es como encontrar el numero mayor de los datos ingresados en la lista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu puedes utilizar la librería Math para ello.

Si tu lista se compone solamente de números puedes usar:

`Math.max.apply(Math, $scope.numeros)`

Si tu lista es un objecto y quieres saber el mayor de uno de sus campos

`Math.max.apply(Math,$scope.numeros.map(function(num){return num.field;}))`

Estas dos opciones te devolverán únicamente el valor mayor.
En el caso de que sea un objeto, no te devolverá el item, solamente el valor del field que le hayas indicado